# Customzing the Vaadin CRM Sample for Bluemix

Tags: java, vaadin, ibm-cloud

Now this is weird, at least horrible documented.
I want to use the Vaadin boilerplate app on Bluemix to customize it later on my local environment (WLP).
Steps I did so far:

- Created the app itself on Bluemix
- Downloaded the app starter from
  Vaadin, build with mvn and deployed it. CRM app was running instead of the satic page
  Bluemix created earlier (source: https://hub.jazz.net/project/vaadin/vaadin-jpa-app/overview)
- Created GIT repo and downloaded it
- Imported everything in Eclipse

In the GIT nothing was there, libs are missing (dep-jar) and even a source folder is missing. What did I miss? The documentation says nothing about how to do it. I wonder, how this app could be deployed on Bluemix then...

Comment: **First**: Which git repo did you use? **Second**: [There](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-boilerplate-in-bluemix) is a instruction how to get started with Bluemix and Vaadin - search for _steps_. There is information that you should Maven (mvn install) - this should download all libs.

Comment: I updated my question and yes, I did the steps provided on the page you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The default git repository when you click the Add Git button for this third party boilerplate will only contain a static Liberty web application code structure - not the vaadin application. You need to override the contents with the code in 
https://hub.jazz.net/project/vaadin/vaadin-jpa-app/overview

There is however a much simpler solution. Simply click on the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button in the above link. That will create your own git repo with the right contents, as well as create a pipeline to build using maven and deploy final application to Bluemix with the database service.

Comment: I just tried it: maybe I am too dumb but what I see in that repo cannot be run on a local Liberty Profile as this hasn't the structure of a web application, right?

Comment: The repo contains the full web app, which works fine on Liberty. What are you missing?

Comment: It's a Maven project, so... as an existing Maven project.